# How to Insert the Cursor at the Beginning of Text in a Textbox Using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox which, when an item is selected, is used to populate a set of controls such as textboxes, radio buttons, and the like.  What I want to do is cause the cursor to appear in the first textbox after the selected item is parsed into the respective controls.  After spending time reading a number of posts here and researching on MSDN, I am still unable to accomplish this simple task.

In the code, I have `txtInstName.Focus();`.  I have confirmed by checking the `Keyboard.FocusedElement` property that `txtInstName` does in fact have the focus.  So how do I put the cursor at the beginning of the text in `txtInstName`?  I've tried `txtIns6tName.Select(0,0);` but that does not insert the cursor where I want it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following property

```
MyTextBox.CaretIndex = someInt32;
```

this property gets or sets the insertion position index of the caret.